# Delete elements after it appeared a certain times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame similar like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([['a','b'], 
          ['c','a'],
          ['c','d'],
          ['a','e'],
          ['p','g'],
          ['d','a'],
          ['c', 'g']
         ], columns=['col1','col2'])
```

I need to delete rows after an element appeared a certain number of times. For example, say I want to keep each value appear maximum of 2 times in this dataframe (in both columns), the final dataframe can be like this:

```
[['a','b'], 
 ['a','c'],
 ['c','d'],
 ['p','g']
]
```

The order of rows to delete doesn't matter here. I want to maintain the maximum times of a value appear in my dataframe.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Is this per column or it doesn't matter in which column the element appears?

Comment: Both columns count, if 'a' appeared in col2 after it appeared twice already, it should be deleted.

Comment: Update your results with updated input dataframe?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, try:

```
n=2
s=df.stack()
s[(s.groupby(s).cumcount()+1).le(n)].unstack().dropna()
```

---

```
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    c    d
4    p    g
```

Comment: I have same approach, just different filtering :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way using `stack` then `cumcount` with `all`

```
s=df.stack()
s=s.groupby(s).cumcount().unstack()
df[(s<=1).all(1)]
Out[206]: 
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    c    d
4    p    g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stack the data, cumcount, and unstack back:

```
s = df.stack()

df[s.groupby(s).cumcount().unstack().lt(2).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    c    d
4    p    g
```